# how to open a particular folder using javascript,any possible to using the file handlers here

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In PHP we used `opendir` and `readdir` tag for read the folders. But in javascript can I do it?

The below code uses the `fopen` statement to read the directory and `fread` tag is used to read the folder list of files from that given directory. I have tried in javascript but no responses.

```
var d = fopen(foldername);
var r = fread(d);
document.write(r);
```

In google mostly seen `fopen` and `fread` for using the particular folders,but I cant get it to work. I want to open a particular directory I want to using the directory files like images

Comment: you want to open a folder on an user's machine from the browser?

Comment: yes myfolder cant get

Comment: What you are asking to do is not possible with Javascript, as JS has no method of accessing the files or folders on the client machine for security reasons. Also note that those PHP methods read the folder structure of the server, not the client machine.

Comment: like php file handling functions may added here,Files can be read and written by using java script functions – fopen(),fread() and fwrite().

Comment: ya but any possible to get open a folder inside the JS

Comment: No, it is not possible. The `fopen` and other methods you describe are part of the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` which woud rely on JS including them as an ActiveXObject. This is frankly *ancient* methodology which is *only* supported in Internet Explorer, and over a `https` connection.

Comment: ok any possible to perform ajax call for opening the folders...

Comment: Javascript cannot be used to access filesystem other than selecting files by dialog box. Period.

Answer (score -1):

Using ShellExecute function defined by Shell.application method ,you can open any folder

Here is the Simple sample code,

var open = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");

open.ShellExecute(""C:\\WINDOWS\system32\\", "", "", "open", 3);

Refer the following Link for more info :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx